# different colors for geom_bar and geom_jitter

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to create a plot where `geom_bar` represents the mean of a set of data points and the individual data points are shown using `geom_jitter`. I'd like for the bar graphs to be colored by factor, but for the individual data points to be white.

This is my script:

```
ggplot(dataframe, 
       aes(x = `glucose`, y = `CTV dilution factor`, fill = `cellobiose`))+
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge")+
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitterdodge(), 
              shape = 21, stroke=0.5, size=2.5, show.legend = FALSE)+
  ylab("CTV dilution factor")+
  xlab("glucose [mM]")+
  facet_wrap(~condition, ncol=2)+
  theme_manish()+
  theme(text=element_text(size=16))
```

[image: result]

As you can see, the bars and jitter points are filled with the same color. I'd like to keep the colors on the bars, but for the jitter points to be filled with white.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default way to achieve that would be to set `fill="white"` for the `geom_jitter` or `geom_point` and to make use of the `group` aes, i.e. use `group=cellobiose` in `geom_point` to dodge the points by `cellobiose`. However, when doing so I encountered an error which seems to be a known but still unresolved [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3656).

A possible workaround would be to map on the `color` aesthetic instead and set outline colors to `"black"`  using `scale_color_manual`.

Using a minimal reproducibel example based on `mtcars`:

```
dataframe <- mtcars[c("cyl", "mpg", "am", "vs")]
dataframe[c("cyl", "am", "vs")] <- lapply(dataframe[c("cyl", "am", "vs")], factor)
names(dataframe) <- c("glucose", "CTV dilution factor", "cellobiose", "condition")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  dataframe,
  aes(x = glucose, y = `CTV dilution factor`, fill = cellobiose)
) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", position = "dodge") +
  geom_point(aes(color = cellobiose),
    fill = "white",
    position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = .9, seed = 1),
    shape = 21, stroke = 0.5, size = 2.5, show.legend = FALSE,
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = rep("black", 2)) +
  ylab("CTV dilution factor") +
  xlab("glucose [mM]") +
  facet_wrap(~condition, ncol = 2) +
  # theme_manish() +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 16))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much for your help, stefan! This was my first time using stack overflow and the thoroughness of your answer makes me feel very confident in participating in this community going forward! 
Next time I ask a question, I will try to make use of a minimal reproducible example!